# Why did Captain America cheat on his girlfriend?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, character-motivation, avengers-endgame

In the end of *Avengers: Endgame*,

> Captain America went back in time and stayed there. He married Peggy Carter and grew old with her.

It was surely an emotional moment, but why did he do it especially when he already had a girlfriend named Sharon Carter (ref: *Captain America: Civil War*).

Why exactly did Captain America cheat on Sharon Carter?

Comment: Are you sure they were still dating? There's no reference to her in any of the later movies.

Comment: Plus it's quite possible Sharon was snapped.

Comment: @Paulie_D - She was (according to Twitter) but she was brought back

Comment: Then she's been gone for 5 years.. I think he can move on (or back..heh) in that time. In fact, he says "Gotta move on"....as I recall.

Comment: When was Sharon Carter his girlfriend? All he has to do is say to Peggy “By the way, I kissed your great-niece one time. Cool? Cool cool cool.”, and he's in the clear.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite It *did* seem quite implied at least towards the end of *Civil War* if I remember correctly.

Comment: @TARS: they kissed, once. Don't be trying to tie Cap down! (She also risks her job and possibly her liberty by bringing him classified information. But that doesn't mean he's not allowed to friendzone her!)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Yeah, for all we know, he might not even be into girls. ;-P

Comment: @TARS: for all he knows! He probably hasn't had much of a chance to date anyone.

Comment: @TARS - I always assumed they shoe-horned her into the film specifically to give him a hetero love interest to balance out the Bucky bromance.

Comment: @Paulie_D `she's been gone for 5 years` ~> So what? Did it give him an excuse to cheat on her? Hawkeye seemed happy after getting phone call from his wife. BTW, do you know for how many years young Peggy's been gone?

Comment: She's for all intents and purposes *dead*. But...on the bottom line, and that seems to be a common theme throughout your studies in Captain America's personal life, *not everyone behaves the same* or is necessarily comparable to you or any other MCU character with regards to their handling of private relationships.

Answer (score 9):

It's not really clear what the (canon) status of his relationship with Sharon Carter is after the events of Civil War. They kissed one time and he then immediately went into hiding for more than a year. She then gets herself snapped out of existence for five years.

By the time he makes the decision to go back to the past, he may well have not seen her for the best part of seven years and **there's no good indication that they were even dating (or even Skype-ing) while he was on the run.**

---

In earlier versions of the script for Infinity War, Steve was actually living with her, but that was removed entirely, **with the implication being that their relationship (such as it was) is long since over.**

> *"In previous drafts, a couple of times,"* Markus told Collider. *"Sharon
> Carter was a victim of what we came to realize as we were writing it
> which is that if you're writing scenes that set up people before the
> story has gotten to them such as Steve and Sharon trying to make it
> work in an apartment, they're gonna go because **the movie does not have
> time to catch up 'previously on the life of Steve Rogers.'"***
>
> <sub><sup>['Avengers: Infinity War' Writers Reveal What Happened to Sharon Carter](https://comicbook.com/marvel/2018/05/23/avengers-infinity-war-where-is-sharon-carter/)</sup></sub>

Comment: And, how much time had he spent with Peggy Carter? Again, one kiss and then he got iced. At least, Sharon was a recent memory.

Comment: @ILoveYou3000 - They spent a lot of time together though.

Comment: After that one kiss, didn't they even have some dialogue that seemed to imply the relationship wasn't going to happen? "That was..." "...late", or something?

Comment: @MartianInvader - Indeed. And in my personal experience, when you kiss someone and they immediately leave the country and assume a fake identity, that relationship probably isn't off to the best start.

Comment: @Valorum In your experience? That sounds like you have some interesting life going on :D